# Overlapping Material Issue

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am currently attempting to render a PCB. I have defined a 'copper' material and I am using it for two different components: tracks and pads. However, on my OBJ-generated model, the tracks and pads overlap, and when I assign them the same material, they appear black in the render.
[image: BAD]

Interestingly, I have another PCB where the rendering is fine. I have attempted to replicate the same process, but I suspect I may have forgotten something.

[image: GOOD]

Any suggestions?

Thank you.